# Compare adjacent characters in string for differing case

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working through a coding challenge in python, the rules is to take a string and any two adjacent letters of the same character but differing case should be deleted. The process repeated until there are no matching letters of differing case side by side. Finally the length of the string should be printed. I have made a solution below that iterates left to right. Although I have been told there are better more efficient ways.

```
list_of_elves=list(line)
n2=len(list_of_elves)
i=0

while i < len(list_of_elves):
    if list_of_elves[i-1].lower()==list_of_elves[i].lower() and list_of_elves[i-1] != list_of_elves[i]:
          del list_of_elves[i]
          del list_of_elves[i-1]
          if i<2:
              i-=1
          else:
              i-=2
          if len(list_of_elves)<2:
              break  
    else:
        i+=1
        if len(list_of_elves)<2:
            break  

print(len(list_of_elves))
```

I have made some pseudo code as well

### PROBLEM STATEMENT

1. Take a given string of alpabetical characters
2. Build a process to count the initial string length and store to variable
3. Build a process to iterate through the list and identify the following rule:

`Two adjacent matching letters`  **&&** `Of differing case`

4. Delete the pair
5. Repeat process
6. Count final length of string

For example, if we had a string with 'aAa' then 'aA' would be deleted, leaving 'a' behind.

Comment: What happens when you have the following `'aAa'` in the string? Are only the first 2 chars removed, only the last 2 chars removed or are all the chars removed?

Comment: ...or indeed the last two or only the middle one.

Comment: You should make the constraint "Two adjacent same letters" more clear in your original statement. I assume this means `Aa` should be removed but `Ba` would not

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you for the reply, in the case of `aAa` the first two `aA` would be deleted leaving behind `a`. Your second question is the right assumption.

Comment: Why `regex` tag? Did you intend to write something like `re.sub(r"([^\W\d_])(?=(?!(?-i:\1))(?i:\1))", "", s)`? See [this Python 3.7 demo](https://ideone.com/fh3JQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very similar problem to matching parenthesis, but instead of a match being opposite pairs, the match is upper/lower case. You can use a similar technique of maintaining a stack. Then iterate through and compare the current letter with the top of the stack. If they match pop the element off the stack; if they don't append the letter to the stack. In the end, the length of the stack will be your answer:

```
line = "cABbaC"

stack = []

match = lambda m, n: m != n and m.upper() == n.upper()

for c in line:
    if len(stack) == 0 or not match(c, stack[-1]):
        stack.append(c)
    else: 
        stack.pop()
stack
# stack is empty because `Bb` `Aa` and `Cc` get deleted.
```

Similarly `line = "cGBbgaCF"` would result in a stack of `['c', 'a', 'C', 'F']` because `Bb`, then `Gg` are deleted.

Comment: @Murchie85 does the answer you selected as correct actually produce the correct answer? Your original post had an example of `CaBbA` which resulted in `1`. The accepted answer returns `3`. i.e. it doesn't repeat the process.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, if you want to do it with a regex, use

```
re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])(?=(?!\1)(?i:\1))", "", s) # For ASCII only letters
re.sub(r"([^\W\d_])(?=(?!\1)(?i:\1))", "", s) # For any Unicode letters
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GGpwvh)

**Details**

- `([^\W\d_])` - Capturing group 1: any Unicode letter (or any ASCII letter if `([^\W\d_])` is used)
- `(?=(?!\1)(?i:\1))` - a positive lookahead that requires the same char as matched in the first capturing group (case insensitive) (see `(?i:\1)`) that is not the same char as matched in Group 1 (see `(?!\1)`)

Comment: Amazing! That is exactly what I was looking for, I was trying both loop iteration and regex, but the lookahead was tripping me up.

Answer (score 1):

A method that should be very fast:

```
result = 1
pairs = zip(string, string[1:])
for a, b in pairs:
    if a.lower() == b.lower() and a != b:
        next(pairs)
    else:
        result += 1
print(result)
```

First we create a `zip` of the input with the input sliced by 1 position, this gives us an iterable that returns all the pairs in the string in order

Then for every pair that doesn't match we increment the result, for every pair that does match we just advance the iterator by one so that we skip the matching pair.

Result is then the length of what would be the result, we don't actually need to store the result as we can just calculate it as we go along since it's the only thing that needs to be returned

Comment: You need to catch `StopIteration` otherwise this raises an exception for a string like `Aa`. It also returns `2` on a string like `ABba` which is not the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Really only need a single assertion in the regex to match the pair and
delete it.

`re.sub(r"(?-i:([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)(?i:\1))", "", target)`

Code sample :

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = ["aAa","aaa","aAaAA"]
>>> for target in strs:
...     modtarg = re.sub(r"(?-i:([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)(?i:\1))", "", target)
...     print( target, "\t-->  (", len(modtarg), ") ", modtarg )
...
aAa     -->  ( 1 )  a
aaa     -->  ( 3 )  aaa
aAaAA   -->  ( 1 )  A
```

Info :

```
 (?-i:                 # Disable Case insensitive if on
      ( [a-zA-Z] )          # (1), upper or lower case
      (?! \1 )              # Not the same cased letter 
      (?i: \1 )             # Enable Case insensitive, must be the opposite cased letter
 )
```

Comment: It [does not work in Python](https://ideone.com/7morVN). I posted the [Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524641/3832970)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Works fine in Python. As for your solution with `[^\W\d_]` for any Unicode letters is erroneous as said repeatedly by me. Prove it if you can, I can prove it doesn't represent Unicode letters.